# How to make a nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid manually?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose I have a .png extension map in which the blocked paths are in black and free spots are white. Using OpenCV, how can I get an OccupancyGrid without using any external libraries?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340803/how-to-make-a-nav_msgs/occupancygrid-manually?/) by [ros-noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/50569/ros-noob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Occupancy Grids are probability maps, each grid shows the probability of an obstacle existing over there. So convert png into an array by reading the image using imread. And change the array values accordingly to match between 0 to 100.

---

Originally posted by [pkvk](https://answers.ros.org/users/50579/pkvk/) with karma: 16 on 2019-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros-noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/50569/ros-noob/) on 2019-12-30**:
Okay so, after making the changes to the array I'll just publish it as an OccupancyGrid right?

**Comment by [pkvk](https://answers.ros.org/users/50579/pkvk/) on 2019-12-30**:
Yes, give it the details it's needs under nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid. Interesting taskphase eh?

**Comment by [ros-noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/50569/ros-noob/) on 2019-12-30**:
Oh okay. Pretty interesting indeed hahaha

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2019-12-30**:
I am having the same exact issue. Could you please post the code of the solution if you found it? Thank you very much!

**Comment by [ros-noob](https://answers.ros.org/users/50569/ros-noob/) on 2020-01-01**:
Check [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/340863/occupancygrid-not-getting-published-python/) out. It might solve your issue as well.

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2020-01-02**:
Thanks! It does :)